# Average timediff of 2nd and 3rd datetimes for a group

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the average time in days between a customer's second order and third order

I know that I need to use the `timestampdiff` but am quite at a loss for how to select the second and third dates and need some sort of nest.

```
SELECT CustomerID, 
       OrderDate, 
       diff, 
       avg(timestampdiff(day, start_date, end_date)) AS average_days 
    FROM () o3
   WHERE date3, date2
ORDER BY CustomerID, OrderDate;
```

**Table**

[image]

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: If a customer ordered an item on the same day, how do you know which comes first? by `OrderID`?

Comment: The order ids appear to be non-sequential!?! What's the PRIMARY KEY? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your data set appears to be fundamentally flawed ; Customer 24 bought an item on 2nd April. They then bought an item on the 13th April with a *lower* order_id. How is this possible? And if it is possible, how is it useful?

Comment: The primary key in this case was the ProductID.

It doesn't really matter the order of the OrderID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your desired result, you first need to calculate ROW_NUMBER from your data PARTITION BY CustmerId. Then keep rows only with RowNumber IN (2,3) and then get the DateDiff between two days. The following query will help getting your desired results-

```
SELECT CustomerID,datediff(MAX(OrderDate),MIN(OrderDate)) 
FROM
(   
    SELECT *,
    @row_num :=IF(@prev_value = concat_ws('',CsutomerID),@row_num+1,1)AS RowNumber
    , @prev_value := concat_ws('',CsutomerID)
    FROM your_table A
    ORDER BY CustomerID,OrderDate
)B
WHERE B.RowNumber IN (2,3)
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

Comment: At least it's consistent

Comment: That crack me up a bit @Strawberry

Comment: You missed a couple, and this doesn't account for multiple orders on the same day